# Deleting this line <html lang="en"> causes some padding to disappear

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to clean up some code in my html/css. It was like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head> ...
```

And my site looks fine like this: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGseL.jpg)
￼
Now, I deleted the first line as I think it shouldn't be there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head> ...
```

But now my site looks like this: [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDTwD.jpg)
￼
The left and right padding of my main .row class disappeared. Can anybody explain that to me and how I can fix that?

Here the site and the full css: https://sleepmee.com/duerme-bien-bebe.html

Thank you so much!

I don't even know where to start :)

Comment: There are two html opening tags.

Comment: Quirks mode is a legacy compatibility rendering ruleset designed to keep compatibility with browsers from the late 1990s when HTML was being standardised. Starting your document with `<!DOCTYPE html>` means "I am a modern browser, don't use quirks mode". In the first example the browser enters quirks mode because it couldn't find a properly defined doctype declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the link and checked out your CSS rules. It appears that there is a rule on `.rows` where you apply your padding as `padding: 20 12 20 12;`. You are missing the `px` here. Try and add `padding: 20px 12px 20px 12px;` instead.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! It was confusing as I didn't need the px before in the first case.